# Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 62 Invalid object table name

Tags: sql-server

How to fix a invalid  object table name?

```
SELECT Proc_Code
FROM ClinicProcedures
WHERE Proc_Code NOT IN (SELECT Proc_Code FROM Patient)
```

Comment: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 62 Invalid object table name` is not a valid MySQL error message.. i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) instead??

Comment: I can't find "invalid object table name" when I google SQL-Server error messages. All the hits are just "invalid object name". Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: And which line is line 62 of the procedure?

Comment: Bear in mind that the line numbers reported by SQL Server error messages are questionable at best.  I typically insert `Print 'marker 001'` tags in my stored procedures while debugging - you can identify the offending line of code pretty quickly that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct database that has those objects.  Most likely, you are in the master database.

Lookup the "USE {database}" command in the documentation.  Alternatively, you can use the full naming convention of objects, and execute in any database:

SELECT Proc_Code
FROM MyDatabase.myschema.ClinicProcedures
WHERE Proc_Code NOT IN (SELECT Proc_Code FROM MyDatabase.myschema.Patient);

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs due to database context mismatching. When users open SSMS, they do not notice that their default db is set to master. You just have to change the database context to the database of current object.